# App doesnt respond to touches after presenting ABNewPersonViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, touch

I want the user to be able to add a phonenumber to the contact book, so I added the code below.

My UITableView implements ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate, and the view shows properly, and also hides properly.

BUT, after the ABNewPersonViewController has been popped, my original view (the one that is covered by ABNewPersonViewController) doesnt react to touches anymore.

Any guesses why? It's UIButtons that doesnt react to both UIControlEventTouchUpInside and UILongPressGestureRecognize events...

```
- (void)prefilledAddToContactsWith:(NSString*)number
{
    // Create the pre-filled properties
    ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;

    CFStringRef phoneNumberValue = (__bridge CFStringRef)number;
    CFStringRef phoneNumberLabel = (__bridge CFStringRef)@"home";

    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumber, phoneNumberValue, phoneNumberLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumber, NULL);

    NSAssert( !error, @"Something bad happened here." );

    // Create and set-up the new person view controller
    ABNewPersonViewController* newPersonViewController = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [newPersonViewController setDisplayedPerson:newPerson];
    [newPersonViewController setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newPersonViewController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: does your original view receive touches after ABNewPersonViewController has been dismissed? If so, it is the default behavior after a new view controller is presented(the old one will not receive events before the new one is dismissed).

Comment: Dont really see what you mean? That is the problem, that the original view doesnt receive touches after the ABNewPersonViewController has been dismissed..

Comment: I see. To know which view gets the touches, you can override `hitTest:withEvent:` and check its return value.

Comment: I will test that. I just learned that it has nothing to do with ABNewPersonViewController, because it's the same if I push another UIViewController.